# NuGet package dll's + content files = fail?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I created a nuget package. I put some files and folders in a "content" folder and it worked great. So I added a bin folder with dll's and put this in my nuspec file :

```
  <files>
     src="bin\*.dll" target="lib" />
  </files>
```

dll's are nicely put in the reference, but the content isn't copied anymore.

How can I manage to get them both working ?

@Edit

I know have this:

```
<file src="content\Controllers\*.*" target="Controllers" />
<file src="content\Views\Account\*.*" target = "Views\Account" />
<file src="bin\*.dll" target="lib" />
```

The package contains the right structure and files, but the files are not copied into my project.

The files are in a folder structure. When I put them directly into my content folder the are copied to the root of my project ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you define a files section in the nuspec we no longer do "automatic" / "Convention" based package creation. We see it as you are telling us what to include so we don't include things not in the list. Simply add the content folder to that list and it will work.

**Edit to include comments from answerer's comment below**

The NuSpec file "files" section tell NuGet where to put the files in the package not in sln/proj when it its unpacked. you want to write it like this:

```
<file src="content\Controllers*.*" target="content\Controllers" /> 
<file src="content\Views\Account*.*" target = "content\Views\Account" /> 
<file src="bin*.dll" target="lib" />
```

Comment: I tried that as well: <file src="content\*" target="\" /> but it doesn work, unless I use the wrong syntax, can you then tell me what syntax to use?

Comment: The NuSpec file "files" section tell NuGet where to put the files in the package not in sln/proj when it its unpacked. you want to right it like this:

<file src="content\Controllers\*.*" target="content\Controllers" />
<file src="content\Views\Account\*.*" target = "content\Views\Account" />
<file src="bin\*.dll" target="lib" />

Comment: So the "content" folder means "root of my project"?  Seems strange... and essentially undocumented.  This page mentions the content folder but doesn't explain why it's special: http://nuget.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=File%20Element%20Specification

Comment: I think this seemingly simple and common thing in NuGet has been made very hard and arcane by the NuGet team. I've spent two days trying to make a simple package that deploys a handful of files.